# How to replace those zero's to one's which are enclosed by one

Tags: c, matrix

How can I replace all the zero to one (only those which are enclosed by one )

Case 1

Input matrix

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 1 1

Output matrix :

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1

Case 2 :

Input matrix

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

Output matrix:

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

Comment: What have you tried, it would help us help you if we know where you were stuck? The concept of *"neighbors*" and array bounds are all you need work with.

Comment: With all of 15 questions asked you should really know this, but *please* take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only concerned about the neighbors for *interior* elements of your 2D array, simply looping over the array bounds with nested loops from `1 < rows - 1` and `1 < cols - 1` would give you the *interior* elements to check neighbors for. You then just check if the neighbors *above and below* are both `1`, if so, make the current element `1`, and then repeat the check for neighbors to the *left and right*.

A simple brute force check is an easy way to start, e.g. where `r` is the rows and `NCOLS` the colums:

```
for (int i = 1; i < r - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < NCOL - 1; j++)
        /* check neighbors */
        if ((a[i-1][j] && a[i+1][j]) || /* above/below */
            (a[i][j-1] && a[i][j+1]))   /* left/right  */
            a[i][j] = 1;
```

That will check whether any interior value has elements of `1` above and below, or to the left/right and set the current element to `1`. It will ignore all perimeter elements leaving your final row `1 1 1 0 1` unchanged.

For a short example testing the code on both arrays, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NCOL 5

int main (void) {

#ifdef W3X5
    int a[][NCOL] = {{1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1},
                    {1,1,1,1,1}},
#else
    int a[][NCOL] = {{1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1},
                    {1,1,1,0,1}},
#endif
        r = sizeof a/sizeof *a;

    for (int i = 1; i < r - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < NCOL - 1; j++)
            /* check neighbors */
            if ((a[i-1][j] && a[i+1][j]) || /* above/below */
                (a[i][j-1] && a[i][j+1]))   /* left/right  */
                a[i][j] = 1;

    /* output resulting array */
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)
            printf (" %d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Compile for check for 3x5 example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -DW3X5 -o bin/arsz3x5 arsz.c
```

Output

```
$ ./bin/arsz3x5
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
```

Compile for full 5x5 example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/arsz arsz.c
```

Output

```
$ ./bin/arsz
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 0 1
```

**Compiling on Windows/C89**

If you are on windows, then you simply need to change the variable declarations to comply with the C89 standard, e.g. you need only move the declarations for `i, j` out of the loops and then compile with `cl.exe` (VS):

```
...
#endif
        i, j, r = sizeof a/sizeof *a;

    for (i = 1; i < r - 1; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < NCOL - 1; j++)
            /* check neighbors */
            if ((a[i-1][j] && a[i+1][j]) || /* above/below */
                (a[i][j-1] && a[i][j+1]))   /* left/right  */
                a[i][j] = 1;

    /* output resulting array */
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)
            printf (" %d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

and then compile with:

```
> cl /nologo /Wall /Ox /DW3X5 /Foobj/arsz3x5 /Febin/arsz3x5 /Tc arsz.c
```

and

```
> cl /nologo /Wall /Ox /Foobj/arsz /Febin/arsz /Tc arsz.c
```

(You can remove the `/Fo` and `/Fe` options if you do not place your object files and executables in separate directories, `obj` and `bin`, above)